# How to select values from table based on field with the same id?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have following sql tables:

Table "**student**"

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lillian | Nees |
| 2 | William | Lorenz |
| 3 | Mary | Moore |
| 4 | Giselle | Collins |
| 5 | James | Moultrie |
| 6 | John | Rodriguez |

Table "**exam_result**":

| exam_result_id | subject_id | student_id | mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 49 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 21 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 81 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 33 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 | 19 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 | 46 |
| 7 | 1 | 5 | 55 |
| 8 | 3 | 5 | 75 |
| 9 | 2 | 5 | 60 |
| 11 | 1 | 6 | 86 |
| 12 | 2 | 6 | 92 |
| 13 | 3 | 6 | 48 |
| 14 | 4 | 6 | 78 |

I need to select all students, who have all their exam marks <50 or haven't taken any exam at all.

So, in this case I need students with id 1, 2 and 4.

Closest thing I came up with is the following query, but it gives students with id 1, 2, 4 and 6. I don't need a student with id 6, since he has only 1 failed exam, not all of them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
FROM university.student s
LEFT JOIN
    university.exam_result er ON
        s.id = er.student_id
WHERE er.mark < 50 OR er.mark IS NULL;
```

I need it to work in both PostgreSQL and MariaDB, so I don't want anything specific to them.

Comment: I'd use NOT EXISTS correlated subquery.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2):

The query that works is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
FROM university.student s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM university.exam_result er WHERE s.id = er.student_id AND er.mark > 49);
```

Thanks, @jarlh for your comment.

Comment: Yes. just like that. (Well, no need for SELECT **DISTINCT**.)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a NOT EXISTS condition combined with a check for the marks

```
select s.*
from student s
where not exists (select * 
                  from exam_result er
                  where er.student_id = s.id)
   or 50 >= all (select er.mark
                 from exam_result er
                 where er.student_id = s.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is doing this with aggregation, by ensuring the count of marks less than 50 is equal to all the count of their marks. When the student has 0 marks, the condition will still be satisfied.

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
FROM      student s
LEFT JOIN exam_result er ON s.id = er.student_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN er.mark < 50 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(er.mark)
```

Check the [MariaDB demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QizC7U2_) and [PostgreSQL demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xaZs5bJSaP7Qke4KGCq23b/0).